# Projects feature with attachments from one coordinate system to another

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5

I'm trying to projects a feature with attachments from one coordinate system to another without loosing the attachments.

I'm using the `GeoTagged Photos To Points` function to create a point feature class which also contains the photos as attachments.

Unfortunately this function does not provide an option to reproject the output feature class. And if I use the `project_management` function, I lose the attachments.

Minimal example:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.maintainAttachments = True 
# maintainAttachments work for the following function:
# - Append
# - Copy
# - Copy Features
# - Copy Rows
# - Feature Class To Feature Class
# - Merge
# - Table To Table
arcpy.GeoTaggedPhotosToPoints_management(folder, photo_gps, "", "ALL_PHOTOS", "ADD_ATTACHMENTS")
arcpy.Project_management(photo_gps, photo_gps_proj, out_coordinate_system)
```

But unfortunately `photo_gps_proj` do not contains the attachments !

How can I project `photo_gps` and keep the attachments ?

Comment: That tool does support the outputcoordinatesystem environment setting, although I would suggest also setting the transformation you want in the environment too.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution by myself:

I reproject my original feature (oFC) to obtain the projected feature (pFC), then I change the projection system of oFC and I copy the shape of pFC:

```
# Reprojection
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(2056) #define the new projection
arcpy.Project_management (featurename, featurename+'_proj', sr,'CH1903+_To_WGS_1984_1') # create the projected feature
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(featurename, sr) #change the projection of the original feature

# Replace the shape of oFC with the shape of pFC
edit = arcpy.da.Editor(arcpy.env.workspace)  
edit.startEditing(False, True)  
edit.startOperation()  

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(featurename+'_proj', ["GUID", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor1:
    for row1 in cursor1:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(featurename, ["GUID", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor2:
            for row2 in cursor2:
                if row1[0] == row2[0]:
                    row2[1] = row1[1]
                    cursor2.updateRow(row2)

edit.stopEditing(True)

arcpy.RecalculateFeatureClassExtent_management(featurename)

# Delete the unecessary feature:
if arcpy.Exists(featurename+'_proj'):
    arcpy.Delete_management(featurename+'_proj')
```

Work like a charm.